# How to redownload an in-App purchase application programmatically

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am able to implement in-App purchase successfully. I am also able to purchase a product through in - App purchase.I am storing purchase information in NSUserDefaluts.So if next time user tries to purchase same product again i am able to handle it locally.My problem is if a user deletes the application from the device,How do i handle the re-downloading of the application without charging for the same product again.I know that if an application has been deleted from the device having in App purchase it has to be downloaded again.Can anybody show a sample code for the same?

Thanks
Aditya

Hi
Thanks for a prompt reply.I have implemented the same as you have suggested.What i'm wondering is if i delete my app and install it again , i am asked to purchase it again.Do i have to pay again for the upgrade or is it handled from the apple server(i.e if i upgrade the same product again am i charged again?).Is there a way to know it was upgraded without asking to upgrade again?

Comment: No, you don't need to pay again for the upgrade. Instead, on first launch, you should call the method I pointed to, to get from Apple the list of previous purchased made by the user. This list is stored on Apple's servers; deleting/reinstalling the app doesn't impact this list, so you should rely on it.

Comment: In other words, the way you could handle this is: - on app start, see if there are any items still needing to be purchased in your game; if yes, then try to get the restoreCompletedTransactions list from Apple and upgrade the items.  This way you can handle both app delete/reinstall, as well as app usage on multiple shared devices(you know one app can be used on up to 5 devices of the same iTunes user account).

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on your answer? I got what you are trying to say, but would be nice if you can explain a bit in detail.

Comment: Can you please explain how to check the receipt of previous purchases.

Comment: look in the help for the restoreCompletedTransactions method. You'll get a dictionary that contains all the purchases ids made by that user for the current app (regardless of reinstalls)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The StoreKit api takes care of this and gives you, on request, a list of identifiers of the purchased items. Once you got those, it's up to you to re-download the products again(if not already bundled inside the app).

Excerpt from the StoreKit API help:

> `-(void)restoreCompletedTransactions`
>
> Asks the payment queue to restore previously completed purchases.
>
> Your application calls this method to restore transactions that were previously finished so that you can process them again. For example, your application would use this to allow a user to unlock previously purchased content onto a new device.
>
> When you create a new product to be sold in your store, you choose whether that product can be restored or not. See the In App Purchase Programming Guide for more information.
>
> The payment queue will deliver a new transaction for each previously completed transaction that can be restored. Each transaction includes a copy of the original transaction.

Answer (score 1):

////Comments pseudo code////

// Reinstall App:

// Restore already purchased transactions...

// Does the NSUserDefaults have the Purchase History??? -

// YES: Load the Table View of Items remaining for sale, Else -

// NO: Get the restoreCompletedTransactions list from Apple

// and create a container to hold previous transaction purchases.

// Fresh new App install:

// When a user makes the first IAP. Add it to the container and NSUserDefaults

// This container will be added to the NSUserDefaults when at least one purchase has been made.